# jquery jqplot jqplot.highlighter displaying the series name in multy series chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a multi-series chart and want to highlight not only `x` and `y` coordinates of the point, but also the `series` name.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way I found to do it is like this:

```
$.jqplot('chart-id', values, {
    series: [ 
              {
                  highlighter: { formatString: 'serie1: %s, %s'}
              },
              ...
            ]
     axes : {
         xaxis:{
             renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
             tickOptions:{
                 formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d'
             }
         },
         yaxis:{
              tickOptions:{
                  formatString:'%.2f'
              }
         }
     },
     highlighter: {
         show: true
     }
  });
```

Comment: This worked for me, requires very little in the way of code changes and importantly does not touch the core jqPlot code. Should be the accepted answer for my money.

Comment: This way worked perfectly for me thanks. I simply added it to each series and worked.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same functionality. I found this post

http://groups.google.com/group/jqplot-users/browse_thread/thread/edcbe2a30ef5052b/622626628106cdc6?lnk=gst&q=series+name+in+highlighter#622626628106cdc6

After reading this and examining the code, I made changes to plugins/jqplot.highlighter.js, line 292 (v1.0.0b2_r947) This is the "case 'xy'" block from switch (opts.tooltipAxes).

out:

```
str = xstr;
```

in:

```
str = series.label + ": ";
str += xstr;
```

Now my series name is shown in the data point tool tips :) You could probably extend this by adding a new switch to the series options, but I wanted it to be on all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same functionality. But I prefared not to change the jqplot scripts myself and I used the solution presented [here](https://bitbucket.org/jab/jqplot/src/7b04867887bb/examples/highlighter2.html).

It is fairly straight forward. The benefit of this solution is that you can modify content of the tooltip without modifying the jqplot script. This way your code is independent of future updates.

For example, see below my solution, built extending [the aforementioned example](https://bitbucket.org/jab/jqplot/src/7b04867887bb/examples/highlighter2.html):

```
function myMove (ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    if (neighbor == null ) {
        $('#myToolTip').fadeOut();
    }
    if (neighbor != null ) {     
        var seriesName = plot.series[neighbor.seriesIndex].label;
        var x = neighbor.data[0];
        var y = neighbor.data[1];
        if(!lastNeighbor || (lastNeighbor.seriesIndex !== neighbor.seriesIndex || lastNeighbor.pointIndex !== neighbor.pointIndex)){
            var myText = "Series name="+seriesName+"<br/>Value="+y;
            $('#myToolTip').html(myText).css({left:gridpos.x, top:gridpos.y}).fadeIn();
        }
    }
    lastNeighbor = neighbor;
}
var lastNeighbor = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Julien Grenier is nice but it's headache when you don't know the name of your series. For example automatically bounded from DB.
There is no need to change the jqplot.highlighter.js. It's not documented but you have *tooltipContentEditor*

```
 highlighter: {
                // you can have anything here
                 tooltipFormatString: '<b><i><span style="color:red;">%.2f</span></i></b>',
                 tooltipContentEditor: function (str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
                 //the str is the ready string from tooltipFormatString
                 //depending on how do you give the series to the chart you can use plot.legend.labels[seriesIndex] or plot.series[seriesIndex].label
                     return '<b><span style="color:blue;">' + plot.legend.labels[seriesIndex] + ': </span></b>' + str;
                 }
             },
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion